# Multiplication of Dedekind cuts - PMA, W. Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am trying to prove that the multiplication of two cuts $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfies the axioms - closed under multiplication, commutative, associative, has a multiplicative identity and inverse. Rudin skips this part, but as an exercise I am attempting to do it myself. Could someone check my proofs. Any help/inputs would be great!

We confine ouselves to $\mathbb{R^+}$, the set of all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha>0^{*}$.

> **Define**
>
> $\alpha\beta:=\{p:p<rs,\text{for some choice of }r,s>0,r\in\alpha,s\in\beta\}$
>
> $1^{*}=\{q<1:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

**Multiplication axioms M(1-5)**

***(M1) Is $\alpha\beta$ closed under multiplication, i.e. is $\alpha\beta$ also a cut?***

(a) *Non-trivial:*

It is clear that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-empty sets, so $\alpha\beta\ne\phi$.

Also, $\alpha\ne\mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta\ne\mathbb{Q}$, both have an upper bound. Since, $\alpha\beta$ is the set all p, no greater than $rs$, $\alpha\beta$ also has an upper bound. It follows that $\alpha\beta\ne\mathbb{Q}$.

(b) *Closed downward*

$\alpha$ is closed downward.

If $r\in\alpha$ and $v<r$, then $v\in\alpha$.

$\beta$ is closed downward.

If $s\in\beta$ and $w<s$, then $w\in\beta$.

As $\alpha\beta$ is the set of all $p<rs$, and $vw < rs$, $vw\in\alpha\beta$.

Hence, $\alpha\beta$ is closed downward.

(c) *No largest member*

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no largest members.

If $r\in\alpha$, $r<v$ for some $v\in\alpha$

If $s\in\beta$, $s<w$ for some $w\in\beta$

It follows, that for some $vw\in\alpha\beta$, $rs<vw$.

Hence, $\alpha\beta$ has no largest member.

Therefore, $\alpha\beta$ is a cut.

***(M2) Commutativity. Is multiplication of two cuts commutative? Is  $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$?***

Yes, this follows from the fact that multiplication of rationals is commutative.

***(M3) Associativity. Is multiplication of cuts associative? Is  $(\alpha\beta)\gamma=\alpha(\beta\gamma)$?***

Yes, this is true, as multiplication of rationals is associative.

***(M4) Multiplicative identity. Is $\alpha\cdot{1^{*}}=\alpha$?***

(a) *Prove that $\alpha\cdot{1^{*}}\subset\alpha$*

Take $r\in\alpha$, $s\in{1^{*}}$, $s<1$, then $rs<r$.

Thus, $\alpha\cdot{1^{*}}\subset\alpha$

(b) *Prove that $\alpha\subset\alpha\cdot{1^{*}}$*

Let's pick $r\in\alpha$ and $r>{1^{*}}$. As $\alpha$ is a cut, it satisfies no largest member property. Hence, we must have $r<s$ for some $s\in\alpha$. Therefore, $r\cdot\frac{1}{s}<1$, where $\frac{1}{s}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $s$.

Thus, we can write

$r={s}\cdot{r}\cdot\frac{1}{s}$

Thus, $\alpha\subset{1^{*}}\cdot\alpha$

**Hence, $\alpha\cdot{1^{*}}=\alpha$**

***(M5) Multiplicative inverse. Is $\alpha\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}=1^{*}$?***

> **Define**
>
> $\frac{1}{\alpha}=\{p:p<\frac{1}{r}\text{ for some }r\in\alpha\}$

(a) *Prove that $\alpha\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}\subset{1^{*}}$*

For the sake of concreteness, I assume that the cut $\alpha$ is the number 4. Then, the cut $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is the number $\frac{1}{4}$.

Let's choose any rational $r$ in $\alpha$, e.g. $3\in\alpha$ and a rational $s$ in $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, e.g. $\frac{1}{5}\in\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Clearly, $\frac{1}{s}=5$ is not in $\alpha$.

$\therefore{r<\frac{1}{s}}$

$\implies{rs<1}$

$\implies{\alpha\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}\subset{1^{*}}}$

(b) *Prove that ${1^{*}}\subset\alpha\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}$*

I am not quite sure of the approach to prove this. Part (b) of the corresponding additive inverse proof in Rudin's proof is also not very clear to me.

Thanks,

Quasar.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if the question is not relevant here, but it would be nice if someone took a look at it. :)

Comment: I have not read all of your post, but there's already an issue in (M1-b).  If $v < r$ and $w < s$, then in general it is not true that $vw < rs$.  For instance, $v=w=-1$, $r=s=1/2$.  You can fix this by assuming that $v,w>0$, but that doesn't help here because you don't really need $v,w$.  Indeed, if $q$ is such that $q < p$, then $q < p < rs$ and you're done.

Comment: @Glitch thanks for pointing this out. I am sort of stuck, can't think of a way to proceed, when I think about the negative numbers which are also present in the cuts $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Any help would be nice!